# Synchronize video and audio (preferably without JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

If I have HTML5 `video` and `audio` elements, is there a clean way to keep them in sync? They should act like a video file that contains an audio track, so advancing one track manually should bring the other one along with it. Let's say the two tracks have the same duration.

I'd like a solution that works across browsers, but I don't particularly care if it works on older browsers. It would also be nice to avoid the use of JavaScript if possible. Otherwise, a dead-simple JavaScript library would be best -- something that only asks for which tracks to synchronize and takes care of the rest.

I've looked into [mediagroup](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1092)... but it looks like it only works in Safari. I've looked into [audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks)... but the user has to enable the feature in Firefox.

I've looked into [Popcorn.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/commits/master), which is a JavaScript framework that seems designed for this task... but it looks like there hasn't been any activity in over a year. Besides that, the only demonstrations I can find are of synchronizing things like text or slides to video, not audio to video.

Comment: Is it at all possible to add the audio to your video beforehand in an external program? It would be the most reliable way of syncing the two.

Comment: *"without JavaScript"*, I would say this is out of the question, but you basically to listen for buffer event on both elements, and stop them both. Then, continue playing when enough data is loaded. Repeat.

Comment: @Glen Despaux I'm looking to avoid that, too...

Comment: You may be asking too much of what HTML can do on its own, then...

Comment: @GlenDespaux is right, HTML deals with the structure of the document not its behaviour.

Comment: Is requirement to not use `javascript`?

Comment: @guest271314 not a requirement, just a preference. I was hoping HTML5 would take care of it...

Comment: @user1475412 Are audio, video tracks not currently playing synchronously using `.play()`?

Comment: @guest271314 they fall out of sync: http://html5demos.com/two-videos

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to synchronize video and audio. Here are links: goo.gl/7gI4jC and goo.gl/7gI4jC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()`, `fetch()` to retrieve media resource as a `Blob`, `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a `Blob URL` of resource; `canplaythrough` event and `Array.prototype.every()` to check if each resource can play; call `.play()` on each resource when both resources can play

> I didn't make it clear in the question. I meant that the two tracks
>   should stay in sync as though playing a regular video file with audio.

One approach could be to create a timestamp variable, utilize `seeked` event to update `.currentTime` of elements when set variable is greater than a minimum delay to prevent `.currentTime` being called recursively.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button>load media</button>
  <br>
  <div id="loading" style="display:none;">loading media...</div>
  <script>
    var mediaBlobs = [];
    var mediaTypes = [];
    var mediaLoaded = [];
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
    var curr = void 0;
    var loadMedia = () => {
      loading.style.display = "block";
      button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      return Promise.all([
        // `RETURN` by smiling cynic are licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License
        fetch("https://ia600305.us.archive.org/30/items/return_201605/return.mp3")
      , fetch("http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4")
        ])
        .then(responses => responses.map(media => ({
          [media.headers.get("Content-Type").split("/")[0]]: media.blob()
        })))
        .then(data => {
          for (var currentMedia = 0; currentMedia < data.length; currentMedia++) {
            (function(i) {
              var type = Object.keys(data[i])[0];
              mediaTypes.push(type);
              console.log(data[i]);
              var mediaElement = document.createElement(type);
              mediaElement.id = type;
              var label = document.createElement("label");
              mediaElement.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
              mediaElement.oncanplaythrough = () => {
                mediaLoaded.push(true);
                if (mediaLoaded.length === data.length 
                   && mediaLoaded.every(Boolean)) {
                    loading.style.display = "none";
                    for (var track = 0; track < mediaTypes.length; track++) {
                      document.getElementById(mediaTypes[track]).play();
                      console.log(document.getElementById(mediaTypes[track]));
                    }
                }
              }
              var seek = (e) => {
                if (!curr || new Date().getTime() - curr > 20) {
                  document.getElementById(
                    mediaTypes.filter(id => id !== e.target.id)[0]
                  ).currentTime = e.target.currentTime;
                  curr = new Date().getTime();
                }
              }
              mediaElement.onseeked = seek;
              mediaElement.onended = () => {
                for (var track = 0; track < mediaTypes.length; track++) {
                  document.getElementById(mediaTypes[track]).pause()
                }
              }
              mediaElement.ontimeupdate = (e) => {
                e.target.previousElementSibling
                .innerHTML = `${mediaTypes[i]} currentTime: ${Math.round(e.target.currentTime)}<br>`;
              }
              data[i][type].then(blob => {
                mediaBlobs.push(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                mediaElement.src = mediaBlobs[mediaBlobs.length - 1];
                document.body.appendChild(mediaElement);
                document.body.insertBefore(label, mediaElement);
              })
            }(currentMedia));
          }
        })
    };
    button.addEventListener("click", loadMedia);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/r51oh7KsZv8DEYhpRJlL?p=preview

Comment: I think the missing piece here is *keeping* the two tracks in sync. They should not fall out of sync and advancing one track manually should bring the other one along with it.

Comment: @user1475412 _"and advancing one track manually should bring the other one along with it."_ This description of requirement does not appear at actual Question?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in the question. I meant that the two tracks should stay in sync as though playing a regular video file with audio. I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is impossible with pure HTML.

You can use the `currentTime` property of both `<video>` and `<audio>` elements to synchronize the time.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("your-video");
var audio = document.getElementByid("your-audio");
audio.currentTime = video.currentTime;
```

If necessary, you could also use the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event to continuously re-sync the video and audio.

Comment: I think this method doesn't work very well... See http://html5demos.com/two-videos

Comment: Looking at the source of that demo, it looks like the times are only synchronized once. It might work better if the `timeupdate` event is used to continuously re-sync them.