# Chrome: to play a video that is being downloaded via fetch/XHR

Tags: javascript, html5-video, fetch-api, media-source, whatwg-streams-api

What I'm trying to achieve is to make Chrome load a video file as data (via the Fetch API, XHR, whatever) and to play it using `<video>` while it's still being downloaded without issuing two separate requests for the same URL and without waiting until the file is completely downloaded.

It's easy to get a `ReadableStream` from the Fetch API (`response.body`), yet I can't find a way to feed it into the `video` element. I've figured out I need a `blob` URL for this, which can be created using a `MediaSource` object. However, the [`SourceBuffer#appendStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/appendStream) method, which sounds like just what is needed, isn't implemented in Chrome, so I can't connect the stream directly to the `MediaSource` object.

I can probably read the stream in chunks, create `Uint8Array`s out of them, and use `SourceBuffer#appendBuffer`, but this means playback won't start immediately unless the chunk size is really small. Also it feels like manually doing something that all these APIs should be able to do out of the box. If there is no other solutions, and I go this way, what caveats should I expect?

Are there probably other ways to create a blob URL for a `ReadableStream`? Or is there a way to make `fetch` and `<video>` share a request? There are so many new APIs that I could easily miss something.

Comment: See  [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency/), [Synchronize video and audio (preferably without JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046644/synchronize-video-and-audio-preferably-without-javascript/)

Answer (score 3):

After hours of experimenting, found a half-working solution:

```
const video = document.getElementById('audio');

const mediaSource = new MediaSource();

video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', async () => {

  const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('audio/webm; codecs="opus"');

  const response = await fetch(audioSRC);

  const body = response.body

  const reader = body.getReader()

  let streamNotDone = true;

  while (streamNotDone) {

    const {value, done} = await reader.read();
    
    if (done) {streamNotDone = false; break;}
    
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value)

      sourceBuffer.onupdateend = (() => {
        resolve(true);
      })
    }) 

  }
});
```

It works with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Also, I tested this only with webm/opus format but I believe it should work with other formats as well **as long as you specify it**.

Comment: @VC.one because it works only on specific codecs. Use ‘MesiaSource.isTypeSupported()’